# My web project does not work on JBoss 7 when deployed by maven

Tags: java, maven, jboss7.x, war, web.xml

I have tried for some hours to get one of my first servlets working on my JBoss 7.1.1 instance. 
I am using Maven to compile and deploy the project as an EAR modul where the WAR file is a part of. I am using maven-war-plugin for making the war module. The structure of the web project is as follows:

```
--src 
   -- main
        -- java
           -- org
              -- myproject
                 -- MyServlet.java
        -- resources
        -- webapp
             -- web.xml
```

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myproject</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.myproject.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myproject</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Myproject</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Myproject` I just get a `Status 404` from JBoss.
I have really no clue on what I am doing wrong.

When deployd on JBoss, the no errors occur in the log and everything seems alright:

```
14:37:15,053 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /Myproject
14:37:15,061 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 26) JBAS018562: Redeployed "myproject.ear"
14:37:15,061 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 26) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "myproject.ear" with deployment "myproject.ear"
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deploying an application on the server, it has its own root path. Thus you need probably to visit something like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/myproject/Myproject`

Comment: Interesting! I have followed the tutorial on http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/ for setting up everything, but I am using JBoss and not Tomcat as in the tutorial. This might be a stupid question, but how do I figure out the root path? All I have set in web.xml that seems to be a part of the path is the `<url-pattern>`.

Comment: I think it is based on the name of the file which is deployed. But to be sure you can specify it in a `jboss-web.xml` file in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` folder: `<jboss-web><context-root>myproject</context-root></jboss-web>`. Also on mkyong, it use an URL of the form `http://localhost:8080/servlet/Demo1` and not only `http://localhost:8080/Demo1`. Hope this can help!