# Deploy on JBoss 7 with maven successful, but web-app not running

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jboss

I created a web app with maven for JBoss 7. During the maven tasks, a war gets created. This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
                <port>9999</port>
                <name>webAdmin</name>
                <username>administrator</username>
                <password>mypassword</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>webAdmin</finalName>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>lightadmin-nexus-releases</id>
        <url>http://lightadmin.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.lightadmin</groupId>
        <artifactId>lightadmin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And this is the web.xml I have created for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>Ifrit Web Administration 1.0</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

So the webAdmin.war file is created and if I deploy it manually (That is, I go to the Jboss web console and deploy it under "manage deployments") I can successfully see the index.jsp under [http://localhost:8080/webAdmin]

The problem comes when I try to deploy it using maven mvn jboss-as:deploy.

These are the steps I follow:

1. Undeploy the war that I manually deployed
2. mvn jboss-as:deploy
3. Go to the Jboss web console and I confirm the war file has been deployed ok (I can see it there being enabled)
4. go to [http://localhost:8080/webAdmin] and I get 404.

I have seen another case like this, in case someone wants to mark it as duplicated saying [My web project does not work on JBoss 7 when deployed by maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318318/my-web-project-does-not-work-on-jboss-7-when-deployed-by-maven) but I still can't make it work. I have created a EAR file too, a jboss-web.xml and it just doesn't show up.

Is there a way to know what context root is the one that has been asigned by Jboss? Or any hint as why it does work when deployed manually vs deployed with maven?

Thanks

Alejandro

Comment: The logs should show the context name. Though I think since you name it `webAdmin` that should be the context name.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too, but I have tried  several combinations and it doesn't work. What really puzzles me is that when deployed manually I can use it correctly... odd

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem where you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently *JBoss AS* could not recognize type of the artifact you had deployed. Try to make it clear from deployment ***name*** in the plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
        <port>9999</port>
        ***<name>webAdmin.war</name>***
        <username>administrator</username>
        <password>mypassword</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no pro by any means but I too came stuck with various little things when deploying my web app into jboss.

I don't know whether or not you refresh the maven build after you make changes to the code, but I found out that that helps quiet a lot.

Deploying with maven usually requires 3 steps (from JBossDevStudio).
Run as "maven clean"
Run as "maven generate sources"
Run as "maven build" .. type in the goals the run enviroment (tomcat:run for tomcat)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately this is not the case. I have done many clean, install and deploy, but the result is the same.